# What is the best method for Socket.io authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, socket.io

My NodeJS server is serving APIs and socket.io connections. The server is authenticating APIs based on JWT access token and refresh token generated at the time of login. The application is serving APIs for an admin dashboard. There is only one type of user and every user has equal access to everything. The only thing I want to confirm is the socket client trying to connect to the server is the user from my client application.

- What is the best and simple way to authenticate my socket.io connections?
- Is a fixed API Key shared between server and client application suitable for this purpose or is there any other simple way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can pass the JWT token as query parameter for the connection request from the frontend. We can authenticate the JWT token in the server during the connection handshake itself and we can accept or reject the request. Client side code look something like this

```js
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000',{ query: "token=abcd" });
```

Where `abcd` is your token which you are passing as query argument.

And server side code look something like this

```js
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    const token = socket.handshake.query['token'];
    // Your JWT authentication code goes here.
});
```

Where `token` holds the token sent from the client. I suggest going with this kind of auth mechanism as

1. Authentication happens at the connection time so rejection and acceptance can be done at the initial level.
2. Every reconnection also authenticates the request.
3. Repetitive authentication won't be there for a single connection thus lowering the authentication time.
4. Changing the JWT token in the middle will lead to closing the existing connection and reconnecting with new token so very very less chances of any attacks.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @sachin is a good pattern but doesn't follow what socket.io recommends which is to use their "auth" handler.

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-options/#auth

https://socket.io/docs/v4/middlewares/#sending-credentials

I suggest the following for your scenario:

```
(client-side)
import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const jwt = await yourAuthLogic();

const socket = io({ auth: { token: jwt } });

// any refresh on client JWT token
refreshedToken()
  .then((newjwt) => {
    socket.auth.token = newjwt;
    socket.disconnect().connect();
  });

// in case of unauthorized
socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
  if (err && err.message === "unauthorized") handleUnauthorized();
});
```

```
(server-side)

io.use((socket, next) => {
  const jwt= socket.handshake.auth.token;
  const isValid = validateJWT(jwt);
  if (isValid) next();
  else {
    const err = new Error("unauthorized");
    err.data = { content: "Please retry later" }; // additional details
    next(err);
  }
});
```